# Filling a list with for loop or Lapply

Tags: r

This is my list:

```
mylist=dput(mylist)
list(list(
        c(30, 50, 35, 25, 45), 
        c(40, 35, 35, 50, 45), 
        c(40, 20, 40, 50, 25), 
    ),
    list(
        c(50, 50, 25, 40, 45, 40, 35, 40, 45, 20), 
        c(40, 35, 40, 40, 45, 30, 20, 50, 35, 25), 
        c(20, 30, 50, 35, 45, 40, 25, 50, 35, 50), 
    ),
    list(
        c(45, 50, 25, 25, 30, 25, 35, 35, 35, 30, 50, 50, 30, 30, 20), 
        c(40, 20, 35, 35, 50, 20, 25, 30, 35, 20, 40, 20, 45, 30, 20), 
        c(50, 20, 25, 35, 35, 30, 50, 25, 40, 35, 45, 45, 35, 45, 25), 
    ), 
    list(
        c(50, 50, 50, 40, 20, 25, 50, 40, 50, 50, 45, 40, 30, 50, 35, 45, 50, 30, 
35, 45), 
        c(45, 20, 25, 20, 25, 30, 20, 30, 45, 25, 50, 30, 30, 25, 50, 45, 20, 45, 45, 50), 
        c(20, 40, 50, 25, 40, 45, 25, 30, 20, 20, 35, 45, 20, 40, 50, 45, 40, 40, 45, 35), 
    ),
     list(
        c(35, 25, 45, 20, 25, 30, 30,  35, 30, 40, 30, 20, 20, 30, 45, 40, 35, 35, 35, 35, 25, 45, 35, 20, 50), 
        c(50, 35, 30, 30, 35, 45, 45, 50, 25, 25, 40, 25, 50, 45, 25, 30, 30, 25, 45, 45, 30, 20, 50, 30, 30), 
        c(35, 40, 50, 25, 40, 45, 30, 25, 50, 25, 35, 50, 50, 50, 25, 50, 20, 50, 40, 25, 25, 35, 20, 20, 50),
    )
)
```

)

```
mylist=dput(mylist)
list
    (
    list( c(30, 50, 35, 25, 45), 
          c(40, 35, 35, 50, 45), 
          c(40, 20, 40, 50, 25), 
    ),
    list(   
            c(50, 50, 25, 40, 45, 40, 35,  40, 45, 20), 
            c(40, 35, 40, 40, 45, 30, 20, 50, 35, 25), 
            c(20,  30, 50, 35, 45, 40, 25, 50, 35, 50),
    ), list(
            c(45, 50, 25, 25, 30, 25, 35, 35, 35, 30, 50, 50, 30, 30, 20), 
            c(40, 20, 35, 35, 50, 20, 25, 30, 35, 20, 40, 20, 45, 30, 20), 
            c(50, 20, 25, 35, 35, 30, 50, 25, 40, 35, 45, 45, 35, 45, 25), 
), 
       list(
            c(50, 50,50, 40, 20, 25, 50, 40, 50, 50, 45, 40, 30, 50, 35, 45, 50, 30, 35, 45), 
            c(45, 20, 25, 20, 25, 30, 20, 30, 45, 25, 50, 30, 30, 25, 50, 45, 20, 45, 45, 50), 
            c(20, 40, 50, 25, 40, 45, 25, 30, 20, 20, 35, 45, 20, 40, 50, 45, 40, 40, 45, 35), 
),
 list(
        c(35, 25, 45, 20, 25, 30, 30, 35, 30, 40, 30, 20, 20, 30, 45, 40, 35, 35, 35, 35, 25, 45, 35, 20, 50), 
        c(50, 35, 30, 30, 35, 45, 45, 50, 25, 25, 40, 25, 50, 45, 25, 30, 30, 25, 45, 45, 30, 20, 50, 30, 30), 
c(35, 40, 50, 25, 40, 45, 30, 25, 50, 25, 35, 50, 50, 50, 25, 50, 20, 50, 40, 25, 25, 35, 20, 20, 50),

 )))
```

I am facing two problems:

First: I can´t run this For Loop below:

```
resultlist<-vector(mode = "list", 5)

for (i in 1:6) {
  for(k in 1:5) {     

    resultlist[[k]][[i]]<-mean(mylist[[k]][[i]]) 
   }

}
```

It sends the message: `Error in mylist[[k]][[i]] : subscript out of bounds`

The second problem is actually a sugestion: My original `for` is much bigger (for example my `i` goes until `4828`), to run a `for` with this 2 indexes (`k` and `i`) there are others functions that would let my code be more simple/efficient or in this situation the best to do is to keep with the `for loop`?

Comment: In your list: mylist[[5]] has only 5 elements causing that the subscript is out of bounds. Moreover the resultlist has only five elements. You don't want to save it as resultlist[[k]]<-mean(mylist[[k]][[i]])  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case , your `mylist[[4]]` only have 5 element, so the error occur because you call the sixth element of it which does not exist.
If all the list elements are equal length, you can use `expand.grid` to find the all combination, and use `sapply` to execute the loop which is little bit faster than `for`
Try this :

```
list_len=length(mylist)
sub_list_len=6
combination<-expand.grid(1:sub_list_len,1:list_len)
temp_output<-apply(combination,1,function(x) mean(  mylist[[x[2]]][[x[1]]] ))
resultlist<-split(temp_output,rep(1:list_len,each=sub_list_len)) %>% lapply(.,function(x) split(x,1:length(x)))
resultlist
```

Comment: Also, double lapply which maybe faster, that solution didn't come up to me at the first time.

Comment: `parallel::mclapply` is a faster lapply, you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that error because the fourth element of `mylist` has only 5 sublists.

You could also do:

```
resultlist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) rep(mean(y), length(y))))
```

to get what you want.